# Create an empty data frame and filling with created columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create an empty data frame and once it is created then add columns to the data frame.

```
InputData=pd.DataFrame()
```

and once InputData is ready as an empty data frame then fill like below.

```
InputData.ix[i,'Quote']=store.ix[i,'QUOTE_ID']
InputData.ix[i,'Com']=store.ix[i,'COM_L']
```

store= my original data frame from which I am trying to get the columns by applying certain conditions. 
quote and com are new columns I want to create and QUOTE_ID and COM_L are existing columns of store file. But i get this error:

```
ValueError: cannot set by positional indexing with enlargement



for i in xrange(len(InputData.index)):
    if (i % 5000) == 0:
        print i,
    if ((InputData.ix[i,'WIN']=='Y') and ((InputData.ix[i,'COM_C']=='H') or (InputData.ix[i,'COM_C']=='S')) and (InputData.ix[i,'COM_QUOTE']>0) and (InputData.ix[i,'COM_L']!=0)):       
       OutputData['Quote']=InputData['QUOTE_ID']
       OutputData['ComList']=InputData['COM_LISTPR']
```

Actually this is the code i am trying to run.
You code `InputData['Quote']=store['QUOTE_ID']`
works fine but when i try this  code where in all conditions are given then does not work on the conditions and gives the same output as in original file. i tried to remove `.ix[i,..]` from the code line but still does not work.

Comment: You can just do `InputData['Quote'] = store['QUOTE_ID']` and so on

Comment: The problem with your code is that those rows don't exist so `InputData.ix[i,'Quote']` is an invalid operation because you're trying to set a specific row that doesn't exist hence the error message

Comment: @EdChum i have edited my question. your code works but when i add some conditions before the code then it does not accept the conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i accept it

Comment: i am unable to post another question yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112505/discussion-between-sanchit-aluna-and-edchum).

Answer (score 0):

Try this for creation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 3, 10, 50], 'B': [2, -8, 3, 7], 'C': [1, 10, -20, 1]})
```

For adding new columns, you can simply define them as in the following example:

```
df['D']=df['C']+5
```

You can assign single elements by

```
df['D'].ix[3]=df['C'].ix[3]
```